# Count groups of dictionary keys using a placeholder

Tags: python, dictionary, count, key, placeholder

The dictionary consists of row-column-keys. Some rows have only one column (r1c1) while others have more (r5c1,r5c2,r5c3...). I would like to count the keys (and so the columns) of every row.

```
row_dic = {'r1c1': (680, 155, 591, 12), 'r2c1': (679, 195, 592, 12), 'r3c1': (682, 241, 587, 11), 'r3c2': (1542, 252, 179, 30), 'r4c1': (1541, 289, 180, 49), 'r5c1': (455, 344, 226, 18), 'r5c2': (688, 345, 573, 17), 'r5c3': (1268, 345, 265, 18), 'r5c4': (1541, 345, 180, 18), 'r6c1': (454, 370, 227, 17), 'r6c2': (688, 370, 573, 18), 'r6c3': (1268, 370, 264, 18), 'r6c4': (1541, 371, 180, 17), 'r7c1': (454, 395, 227, 18), 'r7c2': (688, 395, 573, 18), 'r7c3': (1268, 396, 264, 17), 'r7c4': (1541, 396, 180, 17), 'r8c1': (454, 420, 227, 68), 'r8c2': (687, 421, 574, 67), 'r8c3': (1268, 421, 264, 67), 'r8c4': (1541, 422, 179, 67), 'r9c1': (454, 495, 226, 43), 'r9c2': (687, 496, 574, 43), 'r9c3': (1268, 496, 264, 43), 'r9c4': (1540, 497, 180, 42), 'r10c1': (453, 546, 227, 42), 'r10c2': (687, 546, 574, 43), 'r10c3': (1268, 546, 263, 43), 'r10c4': (1540, 547, 180, 42), 'r11c1': (453, 596, 227, 42), 'r11c2': (687, 596, 574, 43), 'r11c3': (1267, 597, 264, 42), 'r11c4': (1540, 597, 180, 42), 'r12c1': (453, 646, 227, 18), 'r12c2': (687, 647, 573, 17), 'r12c3': (1267, 647, 264, 18), 'r12c4': (1540, 647, 179, 18), 'r13c1': (453, 672, 227, 17), 'r13c2': (686, 672, 574, 17), 'r13c3': (1267, 672, 264, 18), 'r13c4': (1540, 673, 179, 17), 'r14c1': (453, 697, 227, 17), 'r14c2': (686, 697, 574, 18), 'r14c3': (1267, 697, 264, 18), 'r14c4': (1540, 698, 179, 17), 'r15c1': (453, 722, 227, 42), 'r15c2': (686, 722, 574, 43), 'r15c3': (1267, 723, 264, 42), 'r15c4': (1540, 723, 179, 42), 'r16c1': (453, 772, 227, 17), 'r16c2': (686, 772, 574, 18), 'r16c3': (1267, 773, 264, 17), 'r16c4': (1540, 773, 179, 17), 'r17c1': (453, 797, 227, 68), 'r17c2': (686, 797, 574, 69), 'r17c3': (1267, 798, 264, 68), 'r17c4': (1540, 798, 179, 68), 'r18c1': (453, 873, 226, 17), 'r18c2': (686, 873, 574, 17), 'r18c3': (1267, 874, 263, 17), 'r18c4': (1540, 874, 179, 17), 'r19c1': (453, 898, 226, 18), 'r19c2': (686, 898, 574, 18), 'r19c3': (1267, 899, 263, 17), 'r19c4': (1540, 899, 179, 17), 'r20c1': (453, 923, 226, 18), 'r20c2': (686, 924, 574, 17), 'r20c3': (1267, 924, 263, 18), 'r20c4': (1540, 925, 179, 17), 'r21c1': (452, 949, 227, 67), 'r21c2': (686, 949, 574, 68), 'r21c3': (1267, 949, 263, 68), 'r21c4': (1539, 950, 180, 67), 'r22c1': (452, 1024, 227, 93), 'r22c2': (685, 1025, 574, 92), 'r22c3': (1266, 1025, 264, 92), 'r22c4': (1539, 1025, 179, 92), 'r23c1': (452, 1124, 227, 43), 'r23c2': (685, 1125, 574, 42), 'r23c3': (1266, 1125, 264, 43), 'r23c4': (1539, 1125, 179, 43), 'r24c1': (452, 1175, 227, 17), 'r24c2': (685, 1175, 574, 18), 'r24c3': (1266, 1175, 264, 18), 'r24c4': (1539, 1176, 179, 17), 'r25c1': (452, 1200, 227, 18), 'r25c2': (685, 1200, 574, 18), 'r25c3': (1266, 1201, 263, 17), 'r25c4': (1539, 1201, 179, 17), 'r26c1': (452, 1225, 226, 18), 'r26c2': (685, 1226, 574, 17), 'r26c3': (1266, 1226, 263, 18), 'r26c4': (1539, 1226, 179, 18), 'r27c1': (452, 1251, 226, 17), 'r27c2': (685, 1251, 574, 18), 'r27c3': (1266, 1251, 263, 18), 'r27c4': (1539, 1252, 179, 17), 'r28c1': (452, 1276, 226, 18), 'r28c2': (685, 1276, 574, 18), 'r28c3': (1266, 1277, 263, 17), 'r28c4': (1538, 1277, 180, 17), 'r29c1': (452, 1301, 226, 18), 'r29c2': (685, 1301, 574, 18), 'r29c3': (1266, 1302, 263, 17), 'r29c4': (1538, 1302, 180, 17), 'r30c1': (452, 1326, 226, 18), 'r30c2': (685, 1327, 574, 18), 'r30c3': (1266, 1327, 263, 18), 'r30c4': (1538, 1328, 180, 17), 'r31c1': (452, 1352, 226, 42), 'r31c2': (685, 1352, 574, 43), 'r31c3': (1266, 1352, 263, 43), 'r31c4': (1538, 1353, 180, 42), 'r32c1': (452, 1402, 226, 43), 'r32c2': (685, 1402, 574, 43), 'r32c3': (1265, 1403, 264, 42), 'r32c4': (1538, 1403, 180, 42), 'r33c1': (452, 1452, 226, 18), 'r33c2': (685, 1453, 574, 17), 'r33c3': (1265, 1453, 264, 18), 'r33c4': (1538, 1453, 179, 18), 'r34c1': (452, 1478, 226, 18), 'r34c2': (685, 1478, 574, 18), 'r34c3': (1266, 1478, 263, 18), 'r34c4': (1538, 1478, 179, 18), 'r35c1': (452, 1503, 226, 17), 'r35c2': (685, 1503, 574, 17), 'r35c3': (1266, 1503, 263, 18), 'r35c4': (1538, 1504, 179, 17), 'r36c1': (452, 1528, 226, 52), 'r36c2': (685, 1528, 574, 52), 'r36c3': (1266, 1529, 263, 50), 'r36c4': (1538, 1529, 179, 50), 'r37c1': (1267, 1589, 263, 49), 'r37c2': (1537, 1589, 181, 49), 'r38c1': (1267, 1648, 263, 50), 'r38c2': (1537, 1648, 181, 50), 'r39c1': (1267, 1707, 263, 49), 'r39c2': (1357, 1726, 99, 9), 'r39c3': (1537, 1707, 181, 49), 'r40c1': (1299, 1786, 121, 14)}
```

I thought of using a placeholder for the value, but I did not find an adequate solution for categorizing the values in r1, r2, r3. I tried the following, which did not work.

```
for key, value in row_dic.items():
    if 'r%dc' in key:
        counted = Counter(key[:2]).most_common(6)

// counted = Counter(key[:2] for key, value in row_dic.items() if ("r%dc") in key).most_common(9)
```

Output would be good to be something like:

```
counted = {r1c: 1, r2c: 1, ..., r5c: 4, ...}
# or
list = [[1], [1], ..., [4], ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A could first iterate the keys, split the key by `'c'`, then count it with `'c'` included back in.

```
from collections import Counter

row_dic = {'r1c1': (680, 155, 591, 12), 'r2c1': (679, 195, 592, 12), 'r3c1': (682, 241, 587, 11), 'r3c2': (1542, 252, 179, 30), 'r4c1': (1541, 289, 180, 49), 'r5c1': (455, 344, 226, 18), 'r5c2': (688, 345, 573, 17), 'r5c3': (1268, 345, 265, 18), 'r5c4': (1541, 345, 180, 18), 'r6c1': (454, 370, 227, 17), 'r6c2': (688, 370, 573, 18), 'r6c3': (1268, 370, 264, 18), 'r6c4': (1541, 371, 180, 17), 'r7c1': (454, 395, 227, 18), 'r7c2': (688, 395, 573, 18), 'r7c3': (1268, 396, 264, 17), 'r7c4': (1541, 396, 180, 17), 'r8c1': (454, 420, 227, 68), 'r8c2': (687, 421, 574, 67), 'r8c3': (1268, 421, 264, 67), 'r8c4': (1541, 422, 179, 67), 'r9c1': (454, 495, 226, 43), 'r9c2': (687, 496, 574, 43), 'r9c3': (1268, 496, 264, 43), 'r9c4': (1540, 497, 180, 42), 'r10c1': (453, 546, 227, 42), 'r10c2': (687, 546, 574, 43), 'r10c3': (1268, 546, 263, 43), 'r10c4': (1540, 547, 180, 42), 'r11c1': (453, 596, 227, 42), 'r11c2': (687, 596, 574, 43), 'r11c3': (1267, 597, 264, 42), 'r11c4': (1540, 597, 180, 42), 'r12c1': (453, 646, 227, 18), 'r12c2': (687, 647, 573, 17), 'r12c3': (1267, 647, 264, 18), 'r12c4': (1540, 647, 179, 18), 'r13c1': (453, 672, 227, 17), 'r13c2': (686, 672, 574, 17), 'r13c3': (1267, 672, 264, 18), 'r13c4': (1540, 673, 179, 17), 'r14c1': (453, 697, 227, 17), 'r14c2': (686, 697, 574, 18), 'r14c3': (1267, 697, 264, 18), 'r14c4': (1540, 698, 179, 17), 'r15c1': (453, 722, 227, 42), 'r15c2': (686, 722, 574, 43), 'r15c3': (1267, 723, 264, 42), 'r15c4': (1540, 723, 179, 42), 'r16c1': (453, 772, 227, 17), 'r16c2': (686, 772, 574, 18), 'r16c3': (1267, 773, 264, 17), 'r16c4': (1540, 773, 179, 17), 'r17c1': (453, 797, 227, 68), 'r17c2': (686, 797, 574, 69), 'r17c3': (1267, 798, 264, 68), 'r17c4': (1540, 798, 179, 68), 'r18c1': (453, 873, 226, 17), 'r18c2': (686, 873, 574, 17), 'r18c3': (1267, 874, 263, 17), 'r18c4': (1540, 874, 179, 17), 'r19c1': (453, 898, 226, 18), 'r19c2': (686, 898, 574, 18), 'r19c3': (1267, 899, 263, 17), 'r19c4': (1540, 899, 179, 17), 'r20c1': (453, 923, 226, 18), 'r20c2': (686, 924, 574, 17), 'r20c3': (1267, 924, 263, 18), 'r20c4': (1540, 925, 179, 17), 'r21c1': (452, 949, 227, 67), 'r21c2': (686, 949, 574, 68), 'r21c3': (1267, 949, 263, 68), 'r21c4': (1539, 950, 180, 67), 'r22c1': (452, 1024, 227, 93), 'r22c2': (685, 1025, 574, 92), 'r22c3': (1266, 1025, 264, 92), 'r22c4': (1539, 1025, 179, 92), 'r23c1': (452, 1124, 227, 43), 'r23c2': (685, 1125, 574, 42), 'r23c3': (1266, 1125, 264, 43), 'r23c4': (1539, 1125, 179, 43), 'r24c1': (452, 1175, 227, 17), 'r24c2': (685, 1175, 574, 18), 'r24c3': (1266, 1175, 264, 18), 'r24c4': (1539, 1176, 179, 17), 'r25c1': (452, 1200, 227, 18), 'r25c2': (685, 1200, 574, 18), 'r25c3': (1266, 1201, 263, 17), 'r25c4': (1539, 1201, 179, 17), 'r26c1': (452, 1225, 226, 18), 'r26c2': (685, 1226, 574, 17), 'r26c3': (1266, 1226, 263, 18), 'r26c4': (1539, 1226, 179, 18), 'r27c1': (452, 1251, 226, 17), 'r27c2': (685, 1251, 574, 18), 'r27c3': (1266, 1251, 263, 18), 'r27c4': (1539, 1252, 179, 17), 'r28c1': (452, 1276, 226, 18), 'r28c2': (685, 1276, 574, 18), 'r28c3': (1266, 1277, 263, 17), 'r28c4': (1538, 1277, 180, 17), 'r29c1': (452, 1301, 226, 18), 'r29c2': (685, 1301, 574, 18), 'r29c3': (1266, 1302, 263, 17), 'r29c4': (1538, 1302, 180, 17), 'r30c1': (452, 1326, 226, 18), 'r30c2': (685, 1327, 574, 18), 'r30c3': (1266, 1327, 263, 18), 'r30c4': (1538, 1328, 180, 17), 'r31c1': (452, 1352, 226, 42), 'r31c2': (685, 1352, 574, 43), 'r31c3': (1266, 1352, 263, 43), 'r31c4': (1538, 1353, 180, 42), 'r32c1': (452, 1402, 226, 43), 'r32c2': (685, 1402, 574, 43), 'r32c3': (1265, 1403, 264, 42), 'r32c4': (1538, 1403, 180, 42), 'r33c1': (452, 1452, 226, 18), 'r33c2': (685, 1453, 574, 17), 'r33c3': (1265, 1453, 264, 18), 'r33c4': (1538, 1453, 179, 18), 'r34c1': (452, 1478, 226, 18), 'r34c2': (685, 1478, 574, 18), 'r34c3': (1266, 1478, 263, 18), 'r34c4': (1538, 1478, 179, 18), 'r35c1': (452, 1503, 226, 17), 'r35c2': (685, 1503, 574, 17), 'r35c3': (1266, 1503, 263, 18), 'r35c4': (1538, 1504, 179, 17), 'r36c1': (452, 1528, 226, 52), 'r36c2': (685, 1528, 574, 52), 'r36c3': (1266, 1529, 263, 50), 'r36c4': (1538, 1529, 179, 50), 'r37c1': (1267, 1589, 263, 49), 'r37c2': (1537, 1589, 181, 49), 'r38c1': (1267, 1648, 263, 50), 'r38c2': (1537, 1648, 181, 50), 'r39c1': (1267, 1707, 263, 49), 'r39c2': (1357, 1726, 99, 9), 'r39c3': (1537, 1707, 181, 49), 'r40c1': (1299, 1786, 121, 14)}

counts = Counter()
for row_col in row_dic:
    row, _ = row_col.split("c")
    counts[row + 'c'] += 1

print(counts)
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
Counter(row_col.split("c")[0] + 'c' for row_col in row_dic)
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'r5c': 4, 'r6c': 4, 'r7c': 4, 'r8c': 4, 'r9c': 4, 'r10c': 4, 'r11c': 4, 'r12c': 4, 'r13c': 4, 'r14c': 4, 'r15c': 4, 'r16c': 4, 'r17c': 4, 'r18c': 4, 'r19c': 4, 'r20c': 4, 'r21c': 4, 'r22c': 4, 'r23c': 4, 'r24c': 4, 'r25c': 4, 'r26c': 4, 'r27c': 4, 'r28c': 4, 'r29c': 4, 'r30c': 4, 'r31c': 4, 'r32c': 4, 'r33c': 4, 'r34c': 4, 'r35c': 4, 'r36c': 4, 'r39c': 3, 'r3c': 2, 'r37c': 2, 'r38c': 2, 'r1c': 1, 'r2c': 1, 'r4c': 1, 'r40c': 1})
```

**Note:** `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so the result is still a dictionary. If you want the result to be `dict`, then you can cast `dict`:

```
print(dict(counts))
# {'r1c': 1, 'r2c': 1, 'r3c': 2, 'r4c': 1, 'r5c': 4, 'r6c': 4, 'r7c': 4, 'r8c': 4, 'r9c': 4, 'r10c': 4, 'r11c': 4, 'r12c': 4, 'r13c': 4, 'r14c': 4, 'r15c': 4, 'r16c': 4, 'r17c': 4, 'r18c': 4, 'r19c': 4, 'r20c': 4, 'r21c': 4, 'r22c': 4, 'r23c': 4, 'r24c': 4, 'r25c': 4, 'r26c': 4, 'r27c': 4, 'r28c': 4, 'r29c': 4, 'r30c': 4, 'r31c': 4, 'r32c': 4, 'r33c': 4, 'r34c': 4, 'r35c': 4, 'r36c': 4, 'r37c': 2, 'r38c': 2, 'r39c': 3, 'r40c': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of assumes that all the original keys are in the form `r<num>c<num>` but assuming that they are, you could do

```
counted = dict()
for r in row_dic.keys():
    rownum = r.split("c")[0]
    try:
        counted[rownum] +=1
    except KeyError:
        counted[rownum] = 1
```

Then `counted` will be `{"r1":1,"r2":1... etc...}`.

If you want the keys to be in the form you specified `r1c`, I guess just add the 'c' back into the key before you add it to `counted`

```
rowcount[rownum + 'c']
```

Comment: You could probably just check if the key exists beforehand or use `counted[rownum] = counted.get(rownum, 0) + 1` instead of handling an exception. Exceptions are expensive and this one will trigger every time a key is not found...

Comment: Yeah, a fair point indeed. For the set of data shared by OP the performance hit of exceptions seemed negligible, but if it was very large then granted this would be more efficient. I just kept the example simple.